# Angular2 navigate to anchor error

Tags: angular

I use HashLocationStrategy, the routing in my web is ok, and i have the following codes:

```
<a href="#jumpToHere">Jump</a>
<h3 id="jumpToHere">Hello</h3>
```

When i click on `<a>` tag, angular2 throw this exception: EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUrlPath' of null

What is that error?
Please help me fix that error!

Thanks in advance

Comment: provide plnkr or fiddle for your code (Error). i have used the same code in my project but i have't get any error that you mentioned...

Comment: It's here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hipD6Rq1AWTn8VXnQ4w3?p=preview.
Open the console window you will see the exception.

Comment: Basically according to me angular2 ` [router-link] ` after compiling will convert to ` href ` attribute of HTML and here in this question when you define `href="#jumpToHere" `angular will try to find out the router named `jumpToHere` which is not defined in the routing procedure. so it will throw and error message `toUrlPath` of null. To  overcome this error you may try to stop default action of ` href ` tag using javascript (querySelectorAll) and run your according to need it may help you to get rid of this error.

Comment: ok thank you, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Its a conflict with your location strategy `provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})`

with hash-based angular will think you want to navigate to another route when you use that syntax

with path-based, you'll need a [routerLink] to navigate to other routes, so no conflicts
`/yourroute#youranchor`

here is a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3PIVAPEdK8S9hhtZfAsX?p=preview)

Comment: So, any solution for me that able to keep to use `HashLocationStrategy` and navigate to an anchor normally? Because if i use `PathLocationStrategy` when i refresh the page, the 404 error will appear. It may be a bug of angular2 in alpha.

Comment: yes this is bug (404 error) while using `PathlocaionStrategy` . me too facing this error while refreshing page.

Comment: @PardeepJain I think angular team is aware of it, but what do you expect! if you choose to use `HashLocationStrategy `, then hash is reserved and you should find an alternative way to jump to your target div.

Comment: sry i cant get you. yes may be angular team is aware of it

Answer (score 0):

Using [ng2-simple-page-router](https://github.com/bbottema/ng2-simple-page-scroll) you can navigate to anchors within a routed view. Or even pass an anchor id to a new route to automatically jump to:

```
<a simplePageScroll href="#myanchor">Go there</a>
```

And if you want to followup a route with an anchor jump:

```
<a simplePageScroll [routerLink]="['Home']" href="#myanchor">Go there</a>
```

Comment: How to use this using router.navigate() ?